# JHipster - replace default template with a new angular template

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a project generated with jHipster-generator , it's a microservice gateway, and I'm using an angular template called "Gradient Able" (http://html.codedthemes.com/gradient-able/angular-5/default/dashboard/default).

I'm new to Angular , So my question is  :

- What is the best way to integrate the template inside the default 
   jHipster generated angular source ?
- Also is there a way to adapt the future generation of entities to the 
   new template design or I should change every time the component generated ?

Bellow the default template structure :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at creating a blueprint : https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/

Now, you can code a specific generator for the backend or frontend, similar to what is done with Kotlin (see https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-kotlin as example).

You will use only what you need from generator-jhipster:

- client: your own code
- server: jhipster code
- entity-client: your code
- entity-server: jhipster code
- controller and service: jhipster code
- languages: I think you'll need to mix, but not sure

Comment: Thank you pascal for your answer , it's helpful but what about integrating the template in the already generated project ??

Comment: The template is nice and beautiful, but we can't have all templates or features inside our generator. It will be too much work for us to maintain it. That's why we coded the blueprint and module system, so every one can override our generator. We could discuss about it of course if your module or blueprint become very popular.

Comment: thanks ,I just wan to know the best way to override the already generated source code like the login and the layout, the first question is about angular not jhipster

Comment: oh I see, it's for modifying an already generated project. In this case, I only see 2 ways: 1) manually, it will be long 2) coding a module or blueprint, depending if you will use it for some futur projects. Remember the generated code is yours, you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

i think the question is "how to create  a blueprint ?"

i can find lot of documentation or conferences about using a blueprint but its realy hard to find  a step by step tutorial  for creating blueprint.

I ll really appreciate if someone can provide us a  good tutorial about creating blueprint.